# Multiple files upload issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files. And I have implemented the remove file functionality as well.

Code is here http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshNII/ktLsb0md/6/

```
var selDiv = "";
var storedFiles = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#files").on("change", handleFileSelect);

    selDiv = $("#selectedFiles"); 
    $("#myForm").on("submit", handleForm);

    $("body").on("click", ".selFile", removeFile);
});

function handleFileSelect(e) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
    filesArr.forEach(function(f) {          

        storedFiles.push(f);

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var html = "<div><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" data-file='"+f.name+"' class='selFile' title='Click to remove'>" + f.name + "<br clear=\"left\"/></div>";
            selDiv.append(html);

        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(f); 
    });

}

function handleForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();

    for(var i=0, len=storedFiles.length; i<len; i++) {
        data.append('files', storedFiles[i]);   
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'handler.cfm', true);

    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if(this.status == 200) {
            console.log(e.currentTarget.responseText);  
            alert(e.currentTarget.responseText + ' items uploaded.');
        }
    }

    xhr.send(data);
}

function removeFile(e) {
    var file = $(this).data("file");
    for(var i=0;i<storedFiles.length;i++) {
        if(storedFiles[i].name === file) {
            alert(storedFiles[i]);
            storedFiles.splice(i,1);
            break;
        }
    }
    $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

I have an issue with this. When I try to remove the file, from the UI it is getting removed but its stored in the backend, `splice` is not working properly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you seeing the `alert` before `splice`?

Comment: No I added now and saw this itself is coming as undefined! why is var file = $(this).data("file"); not returning file name?

Comment: I added the alert to your fiddle, it worked for me. And when I submitted the form, the removed image was not sent. So it all seems to be working for me. Maybe it's browser-specific? I'm using Chrome 43.

Comment: Try inspecting the image in Developer Tools, to see if it has the `data-file` attribute.

Comment: I am also using chrome. But in my actual code I have removed the handleForm(e) method, since its taken care by activiti. Am I missing something in this?

Comment: Yes it has data-file attribute.

Comment: And the value of the attribute is the correct filename?

Comment: Yes its the same file name.

Comment: Then I can't figure out why it's not working for you. It works for me.

Comment: Hi Barmer, could you please have a look at this: https://github.com/fyneworks/multifile/issues/29

Comment: When you want to send a comment to someone, put @ then their name. And use auto-completion so you spell it right. Regarding your github post, I have nothing to add there that I haven't said here.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry for the typo. Actually I was thinking if you could give some suggestion in fixing the issue with that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/fyneworks/multifile) works almost fine for the problem statement I have raised here. One [improvement](https://github.com/fyneworks/multifile/issues/29) if done would perfectly matches as the solution to my problem statement.